# Remix doesn't compile Selfdestruct with address variable

Tags: remix

Why does Remix compile the below with msg.sender but not with contractOwner address variable?

Thank you

[image: Doesn't compile]

[image: Compiles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selfdestruct` method sends all of the contract balance to passed address and with recent solidity breaking changes all addresses that are receiving ETH must include the keyword `payable`. Example:

```
address payable public contractOwner;
```